# ¿Cómo llamar a este método en Java?

Tags: java, metodos

Necesito saber como puedo llamar al método InicioTienda en java, tengo varios métodos más definidos en este proyecto de la misma forma y no puedo lograr que se muestren.

[image: Captura del código]

Comment: Hola, pulsa en [edit] y pon el código como texto, indicando además cómo intentas llamar el método y qué errores tienes.

Comment: NombreDeLaClase.InicioTienda();